# LINQ & Entity Framework. How to select the whole object and pass as a parameter?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Here's what I'm trying to achieve in Entity 7.

Let's say I have two tables: `Product` and `ProductType`. Product has `ProductTypeId` - FK to `ProductType`. I need to select the whole product object and just one property from `ProductType` and combine them in this class:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string StringProperty {get; set;}
    public Product ClassProperty {get; set;}
}
```

Now comes the query:

```
var productId = 1; //example

database.Products
    .Include( t => t.FK_ProductType)
    .Where(p => p.ProductId == productId)
    .Select(result =>
            new MyData
              {
                StringProperty = result.FK_ProductType.ProductTypeDescription, //this works
                ClassProperty = result //this doesn't
              }
           );
```

The error I'm getting is: *Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression'.*

PS: After looking more at this I think that it might not be a good idea to go this route in a first place. Even if it works `MyData.ClassProperty` would have all `ProductType` table attached to it and that's not what I need. I just need the `Product` class and one single property from the `ProductType` class. Trying to minimize traffic here by using some wrapper classes, but also trying to minimize code needed for that.

But I still would like to know why this approach doesn't work.
Thank you!

**UPD**: Adding Entity's models mock-up per request in comments.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId {get; set;}
    public string ProductName {get; set;}
    public int FK_ProductTypeId {get; set;} //this is our link to ProductType

    public virtual ProductType FK_ProductType {get; set;} //joined ProductType
}

public class ProductType
{
    public int ProductTypeId {get; set;} //our FK
    public string ProductTypeDesr {get; set;}
    //And Entity creates this
    public virtual ICollection<Product> {get; set;} = new HashSet<Product>();
}
```

**UPD2**: Thanks to Evk in comments, removing the .Include statement made everything working.
Still would be interesting to know why.

Comment: Could you post your models for Product and ProductType?

Comment: Just updated the post with models. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to Include( t => t.FK_ProductType). In your code it does nothing useful so you can remove it (and maybe this will also fix problem mentioned in your question).

Comment: Hm, removing .Include surprisingly helped. Would be good to know why :)
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

May be it is EF7 bug? Look at this [discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4167) . Also you can try this solution:

```
var query = (from product in database.Products
            where product.ProductId == productId
            join type in database.ProductTypes 
            on product.FK_ProductTypeId equals type.ProductTypeId
            select new {
               ClassProperty = product,
               StringProperty = type.ProductTypeDescription
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Haven't tried this since Evk's comment above solved the problem, but thank you for your contribution!